# Variables in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have started learning ruby and i have been looking at ruby on rails.Is there  difference in variables and control structures in ruby and ruby on rails?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby is a language. It defines the way you use 'variables and control structures'.

Ruby on Rails is a framework ('large program') written in Ruby. In other words, it's just a bunch of classes and methods. Thus, all 'control structures' come from Ruby itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn Ruby on Rails, you don't have to proficient in ruby. In fast, rails use parts of ruby's knowledge. So, if you have some c/c++ experience, you can learn Ruby on Rails directly, you can learn ruby from learning Ruby on Rails, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is a truly object-oriented language, it contains four variable
such as:

- local variable
- Instance variable
- class level variable
- global variable